# Firefox html5 video is wonky

Tags: html

I'm working on a part of my website where I include a video, like this:

```
    <video style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" src="Witches.mp4" width="1080" height="1920" controls>
      Video is not supported on your browser.
    </video>
```

But the resolution makes the firefox bottom control bar wonk out, like this.
[image: The problem that i am describing]

I tried deleting the css that centers the video and the same problem happens. I don't know if this is just my browser, or something wrong I did in the html, has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aspect is `width="1080" height="1920"`, so it's taller than it is wide, maybe you meant to have it be `width="1920" height="1080"`?

Comment: Thanks :D I also found out that I can just only adjust the height, and it will work fine as well.